Compile time regular expression fails when matching empty string
I have the following code using the compile time regular expressions library:
constexpr auto pattern = ctll::fixed_string{ "\\d+|(?<=FLAGS ).*?\\)|(?<=Subject: ).*?(?=\r\n)|(?<=From: ).*?(?=\r\n)|(?<=To: ).*?(?=\r\n)|(?<=Date: ).*?(?=\r\n)" };

auto all_matches = ctre::search_all<pattern>(header);
for (const auto& match : all_matches)
{
    auto num_matches = match.count();
    auto m0 = match.get<0>().to_string();
    std::cout << m0 << std::endl;
}

I have the following input string:
* 9999 FETCH (UID 1000 RFC822.SIZE 9393939 FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (From To Subject Date)] {132}\r\nDate: Tue, 20 Feb 2024 02:28:43 -0800\r\nSubject: \r\nFrom: Eshy <eshy@example.com>\r\nTo: Eshy <eshy@example.com>\r\n\r\n)

The Subject: portion of the input string is empty. This causes ctre to fail as it cannot move past that point. The same string in regex101, however, has no issue. Is there a solution to this?

Have you tried a simpler regex to see if it works at all?

I'd use Boost Spirit X3 as a parser engine, instead of a regex.  Spirit is an excellent tool to write small grammars.  (It also handles large, complex grammars.  It does take a little bit of getting used to, since it employs extreme operator abuse to express your eDSL grammar.)

@Kevin It works for all cases when there is something after subject.

@Eljay I am pretty much just using std::string_view for the most part. It works very very well and is extremely fast. The issue is I need to implement a much more complex version and I though maybe I might try regex since the std::string_view based code becomes confusing with enough nuance.
